# ioncube installation error on apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, ioncube

I'm unable to make `ioncube encoder` work with `Apache 2.4.12` and `PHP 5.5.8`. So, this is what I've done by now:

```
1. Installed httpd-2.4.12-win32-VC11 [http://www.apachelounge.com/download/]
2. Installed php-5.5.8-Win32-VC11-x64.zip [http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/]
```

Their raw combination works ok - I can run php scripts etc. I then:

```
3. Installed ioncube for Windows VC11 (64 bits) [https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php]
```

I made corrections to `php.ini` and when I do `php -m` I see that it loads ioncube extension without any errors. However, when I now start Apache I get an error with a message about `zend_get_hash_value` and `php5ts.dll`. (PS. Combination with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4 and ioncube works for me, but it seems rather outdated).

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: `The procedure entry point zend_get_hash_value could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have mismatched the thread-safe version of Apache and the ionCube Loader. PHP extensions have to match *exactly* the version that they run on, that is PHP with thread-safety enabled **has** to have a thread-safe Loader.

To confirm this, go to the output of your `phpinfo();` and look for the entry `Thread Safety`. If it says `disabled`, make sure you have the `Non-TS` version of the ionCube Loader ([Win x64 Non-TS zip](http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_win_nonts_vc11_x86-64.zip)). Likewise, if it says `enabled`, make sure you have to thread-safe version of the Loader ([Win x64 TS zip](http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_win_vc11_x86-64.zip)).

Furthermore, please consider using 32bit PHP / Apache on Windows, as PHP 64bit is still marked as experimental and can cause issues with the ionCube Loader:

> The x64 builds of PHP for Windows should be considered experimental, and do not yet provide 64-bit integer or large file support ([source](http://windows.php.net/))

Comment: I know that stuff. Non-thread safe PHP versions are marked like `php-5.5.9-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip`, whereas I have `php-5.5.8-Win32-VC11-x64.zip`, so my PHP is thread-safe. Likewise, non-thread safe version of the Loader are marked as `Windows VC11 (Non-TS) (64 bits)`, but I have `Windows VC11 (64 bits)`, so it is also thread safe. So, there is one-to-one mapping between PHP and the Loader. They are both thread-safe, both VC11 and both 64 bits. And besides, as I said, if I check `php.exe --modules`, I see that PHP loads this ioncube Loader.

Comment: @Jacobian If I remember correctly, PHP will sometimes show the extension as correctly loaded even though it is the wrong version, but crash if you try to actually use it - so I just wanted to make sure :) . Do you *have* to use 64bit PHP? Although the Loader runs through every testcase on our machines just fine, we've had some problems in the past with 64bit PHP on Windows due to PHP still using 32bit values in place of 64bit values, which may cause trouble (although your error may indicate otherwise, will look into it)

Comment: Can you, please, suggest me what combination of Apache 2.4 and PHP I should use then? I spent the whole day and tried dozens of combinations, but to no avail. I tried apache 2.4 + php x86, but got other errors not related to the loader. So, if you have a real working test case of Apache 2.4 + php + loader, I would really apreciate your help.

Comment: @Jacobian XAMPP / WAMP 32bit should work just fine, and is one of the most popular combinations as far as I know. As long as it is 32bit PHP (and therefore also Apache) it should work just fine on Windows.